# python cantools.decode_message() giving data that does not match my Manuel decode

Tags: python-3.x, can-bus, python-can

I am receiving a can message over udp in the format (data_length, frame_id, data) and trying to translate it into json. I am using the cantools library to load a dbc file with cantools.database.load_file() and then translating the message with decode_message(). The message is being decoded without any errors except the values I am receiving are wrong when compared to when I decode it manually and when I use other software to decode the messages. For example, the following data `00 00 03 d0 01 40 00 ad` should be decoded to be `{‘Engine_Speed’: 0, ‘Inlet_Manifold_Pressure’: 97.6, ‘Inlet_Air_Temperature’: 32, ‘Throttle_Position’: 17.3}` but instead it is `{‘Engine_Speed’: 12336, ‘Inlet_Manifold_Pressure’: 1233.6000000000001, ‘Inlet_Air_Temperature’: 1233.9, ‘Throttle_Position’: 2564.8}`. Here is the image of this part of the dbc in kvsar [CAN DBC for this frame_id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzgV6.png)

I have tried reversing the data in 3 different ways:
Given the original data `12 34 56 78` I have transformed it to be `87 65 43 21`, `78 56 34 12`, and `21 43 65 87` but none of these have gotten me the proper value. I also have code that formats the data in a bite string that looks like the following `b'\\x10\\x00\\x00\\x10\\x10\\x00\\x00\\x30'` which fixes the issue for some but not all variables. I have checked that the dbc has no offsets, the scaling I am using is correct, and that the proper bytes are assigned to the proper variables but none of this worked.

Here is the code:

```
`import cantools
import json
import time

def start(receive_socket, socket):
    print('Starting CAN Translator')
    global send_socket
    send_socket = socket
    setup()
    main(receive_socket)


def setup():
    global sel
    global db
    global CANSocket
    global serverIP
    global receivePort
    global bufferSize
    global nonLiterals
    global json_file_name
    bufferSize = 1024
    nonLiterals = set()
    json_file_name = 'json_data.json'

    # Add the DBC file to the CAN reader
    db = cantools.database.load_file('DBCS/DBC3.dbc', database_format='dbc', encoding='cp1252', frame_id_mask=None, prune_choices=False, strict=True, cache_dir=None)

    # Reset the json file
    json_file = open(json_file_name, 'w')
    json_file.write('{}')


def find_nth(haystack, needle, n):
    start = haystack.find(needle)
    while start >= 0 and n > 1:
        start = haystack.find(needle, start + len(needle))
        n -= 1
    return start


# Translate each string from the decoded CAN message into a dictionary and then output that dictionary to the json file
def to_json(message):
    print(message)
    with open(json_file_name, 'r+') as json_file:
        json_dict = json.load(json_file)
        # print(json_dict)
        json_dict.update(message)
        # Add a value to hold the current time
        json_dict.update({'Timestamp': time.time()})
        json_file.close()
        open(json_file_name, 'w').close()
        json_file = open(json_file_name, 'r+')
        json.dump(json_dict, json_file)
        send_json(json_dict)


def reformatter(data_string):
    # print(data_string)
    start_pos = 0
    current_space = 0
    next_space = 0
    i = 0
    data_reformatted = ''
    while next_space >= 0:
        # print(data_string)
        next_space = find_nth(data_string, ' ', i + 1)
        # print(next_space)
        # print(next_space-current_space)
        if next_space - current_space == 1:
            data_reformatted += ('\\x0' + data_string[start_pos:next_space])
        elif next_space - current_space == 2:
            data_reformatted += ('\\x' + data_string[start_pos:next_space])
        else:
            data_reformatted += ('\\x' + data_string[start_pos:])
        # print('looking for more spaces')
        i += 1
        current_space = next_space + 1
        start_pos = current_space

        # print(data_reformatted)

    return data_reformatted


def data_handler(data):
    # Extract the message from the socket
    message = data.decode().strip()

    # Separate CAN message into id and data
    # Except non hexadecimal values
    try:
        frame_id = int(message[find_nth(message, ',', 1) + 1:find_nth(message, ',', 2)], 16)
    except ValueError as error:
        # print('Non hexadecimal frame_id: %s' % error)
        nonLiterals.add(str(error))
        frame_id = 'ERROR'

    print(message)
    print(f'Frame ID: {frame_id}     data: {data}')

    data_string = message[find_nth(message, ',', 2) + 1:]
    data = bytes(data_string, 'utf-8')

    data_reformatted = reformatter(data_string)
    fixed_data = bytes(data_reformatted, 'utf-8')
    # print(fixed_data)

    reversed_reformatted = bytes(reverse(data_reformatted), 'utf-8')

    regular_reversed = data_string[::-1]
    regular_reversed_reformatted = bytes(reformatter(regular_reversed), 'utf-8')

    weird_reversed = bytes(reverse(reformatter(regular_reversed)), 'utf-8')

    to_send = fixed_data
    print(to_send)

    try:
        # Decode each incoming message
        to_json(db.decode_message(frame_id_or_name=frame_id, data=to_send, decode_choices=False, scaling=True, decode_containers=False, allow_truncated=False))
    except KeyError as error:
        print('Key error: %s' % error)
    except ValueError as error:
        print(error)
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)


def send_json(json_string):
    json_result = json.dumps(json_string)

    try:
        send_socket.send(json_result.encode())
    except ConnectionResetError as error:
        print(error)

    # print(json_result, 'was sent!')
    # time.sleep(1)


def reverse(data_string):
    # print(data_string)

    length = len(data_string)
    i = int(length/4)
    reverse_string = ''
    while i > 0:
        startpos = find_nth(data_string, '\\', i)
        reverse_string += data_string[startpos:startpos+4]
        i -= 1
    # print(reverse_string)

    return reverse_string


def main(receive_socket):
    while True:
        data_handler(receive_socket.recv())
```

`

Comment: there are a lot of `globals`. This is a red flag for poor coding practice.

Comment: too much code, please reduce to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example